# Custom Post Type Implementation

Tags: custom-post-types, customization

I have been working hard to implement few custom post types for making a job board in hybrid news. So far, I have created custom post type- Jobs, created a page template http://pharmastudent.net/jobs for displaying jobs which is place in the parent theme.

If I understand the custom post types correctly, I have to create a single-job.php correct?

Rightnow, the singular.php is modified how an individual job should be displayed http://pharmastudent.net/Jobs/manager

I was made aware that modifying singular.php is not the correct way, instead a single-job.php should be created.. Could anyone help me create the same and let me know where it has to be filed?

Thanks much in anticipation.

Naveen

Answer (score 1):

You don't *have to* create a `single-job.php`. Depending on your content, modifying `single.php`, or even `index.php` may be preferable.

The key is to remember the [WordPress template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png).

Your template files go right into your theme's folder, by the way.

Comment: Thanks. But, in a lot of tutorials I read that `singluar.php` is a fall back template. Currently, I have modified `singular.php`, but if that is not correct, i would like to add `singular-job.php`

Comment: I've never heard of a `singular.php` template file. It's not mentioned in the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Single_Post_display) neither.